# BadMethodCallException Method App\Http\Controllers\StoreController::show does not exist

Tags: laravel

I am new too laravel and I'm creating  a blog, specifically the index page where all the blogs will be displayed and when displayed , when a specific blog title is clicked instead of opening the blog post it displays

> BadMethodCallException Method
>   App\Http\Controllers\StoreController::show does not exist.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/','StoreController@index');
    Route::resource('store','StoreController');    
    Route::resource('category','CategoryController');
    Route::resource('post','PostController');
    //Route::resource('user','UserController');
    //Route::controller('mail','MailController');

});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/','StoreController@index');
    Route::resource('store','StoreController');
    Route::resource('category','CategoryController');
    Route::resource('post','PostController');
    //Route::resource('user','UserController');
    //Route::controller('mail','MailController');

});
```

Comment: does `StoreController` available in your project

Comment: yes it does....

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


use App\Post;
use App\show;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class StoreController extends Controller
{
     public function index() { 
     return view('store.main')
     ->with('posts', Post::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get());
            
    }
        
     public function getView($id){
        return view('store.view')
           ->with('posts', Post::find($id));
        
    }
    
    
   
    
    
    
}

Comment: is this the controller

Comment: yes it is, am trying to add an image , how do i add an image here in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Post the HTML code that you are using in order to redirect to the blog page. In addition to that, seems like you are not using Laravel routes as you should.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your controller "StoreController" has show method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your `StoreController`? If you did seems like that your controller is missing show() function, which should handle specific blog show. Did you create it with `-r` flag, like this:

```
php artisan make:controller StoreController -r
```

This will automatically create a resource controller with all necessary methods:

1. index()
2. show()
3. create()
4. store()
5. update()
6. delete()

More about resource controllers in official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: yes i have, i checked my routes and it shows the store controller

Comment: i retried creating again with php artisan make:controller StoreController -r , controller already exist

Comment: Can you put your controller in your original question?

Answer (score 0):

Mine was working well but started throwing errors suddenly.
Create a new controller, copy and paste all the methods from the old controller to the new controller. This solved my problem. Hope it solves yours. For instance my old controller was WebsiteController and renamed to WebController.
Remember to change the controller in the routes too.
Hope someone helps to explain what causes this..